# How i can use the user interface in my Eclipse?

Tags: java, android, eclipse, user-interface

my name is Stephen'm here in Brazil and I'm noob. I'm starting to learn how to develop applications for android and I need a direction.

There are many user interface pack online, but I was wondering how I apply in my application, so maybe I create my own interface pack

Comment: The first sentence left me in hysterics. Have an upvote haha

Comment: sorry, google translate sucks. my english it's very good for read not for write. :(

Comment: It's ok, but as I see you basically want to create user interface for an android app using Eclipse? Right? Not use the UI of Eclipse as you post heading was suggesting (I believe that too was done by google translate!)?

Answer (score 3):

I would start here http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html.  This will show you how to open a android project and navigate to the layout file where you can either add elements with the palette or in the xml.

I think google provides pretty good documentation to get you going.  Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

I will recommnend you to start with that one: is the simple Eclipse ; ) [Eclipse Indigo](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/eclipse-ide-java-ee-developers/indigosr2)
Is the user interface that I use, but I dont know if it works for developing Android apps. Just try and tell us :D

Answer (score 0):

The graphical user interface for an Android app is built using a hierarchy of `View` and `ViewGroup` objects. `View` objects are usually UI widgets such as buttons or text fields and `ViewGroup` objects are invisible view containers that define how the child views are laid out, such as in a grid or a vertical list.

Android provides an XML vocabulary that corresponds to the subclasses of `View` and `ViewGroup` so you can define your UI in XML using a hierarchy of UI elements and hence create you own UI packs.

Reference: http://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/building-ui.html